# Using Tweepy to Follow a CSV File List of Usernames

Tags: python, csv, tweepy

I have a list of Twitter usernames stored in a CSV file that I would like to follow. Right now I'm using Tweepy to follow one username at a time.  How would I make it so that the program goes down the CSV list of usernames and follows each of the users?

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = "XXX"
consumer_secret = "XXX"
access_token = "XXX"
access_token_secret = "XXX"

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
  consumer_key, consumer_secret,
   access_token, access_token_secret
)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

screen_name = "twitteruser"

api.create_friendship(screen_name=screen_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could obviously use "for loop" in order to iterate through your csv.